# Memory Efficient Way to Remove Kth Node from End of Linked List

Tags: java, algorithm, linked-list, space-complexity, memory-efficient

This is a known problem with several known solutions, but my current struggle is to try and find the most efficient way to solve it, considering memory usage (and not time-complexity).

**The problem:** Given a *singly-linked-list* of unknown (but potentially quite large) size `N`, remove the `Kth` member from the end of the list. `0 <= K < N`.

If `K` is `0`, remove the last node of the list. If `K = N-1`, remove the first node in the list.

My initial approach was recursion - it's the simplest to write, and its time complexity is `O(N)` - going over the list twice, to the end and back.

```
public int removeKLast(Node<T> node, int k) {
    if (node.getNext() == null) {
        return k;
    } else {
        int current = removeKLast(node.getNext(), k);
        if (current == 0) {
            node.setNext(node.getNext().getNext());
        }
        return current - 1;
    }
}
```

It had some end-cases that needed solving (like removing the first node from the list) but was otherwise simple enough.

My issue is that this implementation means the entire linked list is stored in memory, with the overhead associated with objects. I wanted to know if a more efficient solution (still in `O(N)` time, running over the list twice at most) could be found, using at most `K` primitive ints in memory at any given time.

Comment: If you had a way to get the length beforehand you could store only the first (len - k) elements in memory by starting from the beginning..

Comment: If you have no further information about the list, e.g. its size, you have no other way than to fully traverse the list. `O(N)` space complexity is as good as you'll get.

Comment: "using at most K primitive ints in memory" - What should the `int`s represent? How should they help in referencing the object (`Node<T>`) to remove?

Comment: Why not just find the size and then go over the list from the start one more time until you reach the required element? You will have O(1) space complexity(all you need to store is the size of the list) and O(N) time complexity(at most 2N).

Comment: If we're talking about maximum RAM usage, you can lazily load nodes from external storage, keeping the last K nodes loaded in RAM. Once you have reached the end of the list, you'll have the last K nodes of the list in RAM and can just remove the first of them from the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start list traversal. After K steps start the second iterator and then walk in parallel. When the first iterator reaches the end, the second one stands on the node to delete.

This approach cannot change O(n) complexity and performs about 2n (2n-k) step operations, but excludes "delay" between end finding and deletion

Comment: It's effectively the same as Bernat's solution, the only difference is the order of operations.

Comment: Of course, there is no way to make fewer number of operations. But instant yield might be useful

Answer (score 1):

Consider retrieving the list size first:

```
public int size(Node<T> node) {
   int size = 0;
   if(node != null) {
   for(; node.getNext() != null; node = node.getNext())
       size++;
   }
   return size;
}
```

Then you can remove the `k`-th before last in one go:

```
public int removeKLast(Node<T> node, int size, int k) {
    for(int i = 0; node = node.getNext() && i < size - k - 1; ++i) {}
    node.setNext(node.getNext().getNext());
}
```

Additional memory needed: 1 variable of type `int` (size).
Time complexity: O(n).

You missed to explain how you store your head node, so this implementation will not work when you try to remove the first node. The modification needed to fix this would be something like:

```
public void removeKLast(Node<T> node, int size, int k) {
    if(k == size - 1) {
        node.setHead(node.getHead().getNext());
    } else {
        for(int i = 0; node = node.getNext() && i < size - k - 1; ++i) {}
        node.setNext(node.getNext().getNext());
    }
}
```